# Enforcing Custom Long/Short Versions in glossaries-extra

Tags: formatting, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I've set up a custom glossaries-extra configuration. I've defined custom commands named `customLongVersion` and `customShortVersion` which are being used inside the `\glsentryfmt` command. However, I'm facing a challenge in enforcing the usage of these custom versions (`customlong`, `customshort`, or `forcefirst`) with glossaries-extra. The default commands seem to be using the standard long/short formatting, and I'm not sure how to override this behavior.

The following screenshot shows the current behaviour and the expected expressed in a table:
[image]

I've also provided a [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/ksrpwksvjcdh#b262e3) via Overleaf for easier reference. And for those who do not want to use the overleaf stuff, here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref, tabularx}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

% Glossary Initialization
\makenoidxglossaries

% Custom Command to enforce "first-use" style
\newcommand{\customshort}[2][]{\glslink[noindex]{#2}{\glsentryshort{#2}}#1}

% Custom Command to enforce "first-use" style
\newcommand{\customlong}[2][]{\glslink[noindex]{#2}{\glsentrylong{#2}}#1}

% Force First Form
\newcommand{\forcefirst}[3][]{%
    % Force the initial representation, however I think it isn't a good idea to do it like this (I had some trouble with this + list of glossaries in the past)
    \glslocalreset{#2}% 
    \gls[noindex, #1]{#2}[#3]%
}

% Custom Command for Long Version
\newcommand{\customLongVersion}{%
    Long\expandafter\glsaccesslong\expandafter\glslabel
}

% Custom Command for Short Version
\newcommand{\customShortVersion}{%
    Short\expandafter\glsaccessshort\expandafter\glslabel
}

% Re-define the Glossary Entry Format
\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \ifglsused\glslabel%
  {Used:\customShortVersion}
  {New:\customLongVersion\space(\customShortVersion)}
}


% Define a new sample acronym
\newacronym{SVG}{SVG}{Scalable Vector Graphics}
  
\begin{document}

Normal: \gls{SVG} is a normal usage with \gls{SVG} as short version.

% Inside the table the result is not as expected!
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXX}
        \textbf{Command} & \textbf{Result} & \textbf{Expected}\\
         \texttt{customshort\{SVG\}} &  \customshort{SVG} & ShortSVG\\
         \texttt{customlong\{SVG\}} & \customlong{SVG} & LongScalable Vector Graphics\\
         \texttt{forcefirst\{SVG\}} & \forcefirst{SVG} & New:LongScalable Vector Graphics(ShortSVG)\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```